# What does it mean when Linux has no I/O scheduler

Tags: virtualization, cloud, ubuntu-14.04, io, scheduler

I have some virtual machines running Ubuntu cloud-based image 14.04-1 LTS version. I wanted to see the IO performance of different IO schedulers on the VM so I went to `/sys/block/<drive>/queue/scheduler` on the guest OS to change the IO scheduler. Usually, there should be `cfq`, `deadline`, or `noop` to choose. But what I saw is `none`. Does it mean that Canonical has removed the I/O scheduler in the cloud-based image or  the scheduler `none` here is the renamed `noop` scheduler? and what happens if we don't have an I/O scheduler in the system? All the io requests were directly sent the host in FIFO order?

Thanks for shed some light!

Comment: Is your server running under KVM hypervisor?

Comment: In most cases, none or noop as a scheduler is best in VMs, as scheduling is already accomplished at least one layer below, at the hypervisor's kernel level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization):

> ## Low-Latency IO-Scheduler
>
> (This step is not necessary for SSDs using the NVMe protocol instead of SATA, which bypass the traditional I/O scheduler and use the `blk-mq` module instead.)
>
> The default I/O scheduler queues data to minimize seeks on HDDs, which is not necessary for SSDs. Thus, use the `"deadline"` scheduler that just ensures bulk transactions won't slow down small transactions: Install `sysfsutils` and
>
> ```
> echo "block/sdX/queue/scheduler = deadline" >> /etc/sysfs.conf
> ```
>
> (adjust sdX to match your SSD) reboot or
>
> ```
> echo deadline > /sys/block/sdX/queue/scheduler
> ```

So, the answer is: `none` is NOT an alias for `noop`. `none` means "the scheduler is not used".

Comment: I'm not sure how the quote brings you to your conclusion that `noop` is not `none`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: As I know, `noop` still makes a few scheduling decisions (like requests merging), while `None` means none at all.

Answer (score 16):

It seems that on kernels >= 3.13 `none` is not an alias of `noop` anymore. It is shown when the [`blk-mq` I/O framework](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Multi-Queue_Block_IO_Queueing_Mechanism_(blk-mq)) is in use; this means a complete bypass of the old schedulers, as `blk-mq` has (right now) no schedulers at all to select.

On earlier kernels, `none` really is a poorly-documented alias for `noop`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664334/selecting-the-right-linux-i-o-scheduler-for-a-host-equipped-with-nvme-ssd) for more details.

Comment: See [another answer for the same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36796882/142239).

Comment: It seems that on kernels > 3.13 `none` is shown when the `blk-mq` I/O framework is in use. So yes, with such kernels, `none` means a complete bypass of the old schedulers, as `blk-mq` has no schedulers at all to select. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

None is not an alias for noop.

None is displayed because no scheduler is in use. SSDs using the NVMe protocol instead of SATA bypass the traditional I/O scheduler.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Please see my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/815980/39806), and [sheridp's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36796882/142239).

Answer (score 2):

Guest VMs have virtual I/O devices provided by the hypervisor. Therefore the actual I/O device scheduling is performed by the hypervisor kernel, and guests pass all device I/O directly to hypervisor without any scheduling.

Comment: Please add something like "assuming the VM has an optimal configuration" and maybe give a tip about how to find that configuration.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/IOSchedulers

none (Multiqueue)
The multi-queue no-op I/O scheduler. Does no reordering of requests, minimal overhead. Ideal for fast random I/O devices such as NVME.