# Is it possible to set an IO scheduler in KVM Guest with VirtIO?

Tags: debian, scheduler, virtio

Is it possible to set an IO scheduler in a KVM Guest with VirtIO?
With the following command i don't get any options to choose

```
cat /sys/block/vda/queue/schedule
none
```

Kerneloption are set:

```
root@jessie:~# egrep 'CONFIG_IOSCHED_.*=y' /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_IOSCHED_NOOP=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_DEADLINE=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ=y
```

[Referred to this post, before kernel version 3.13, none was an alias for noop](https://serverfault.com/a/693380/220267)

Background information:

```
System: upgrade wheezy to jessie
Kernelversion: 3.16.0-5-686-pae
```

Comment: Since your VM has no access to the underlying hardware, it is the hypervisor that actually does the IO scheduling, and the VirtIO driver doesn't even pretend to emulate an actual disk,  I don't think it would make any sense to support any scheduling in the guest OS.